# Transfer Files between two Windows 10 Computers in Local Network Using Python

Tags: python, shutil

I want to transfer a file programmatically using Python between two Windows 10 Computers in a Local Network.

I tried using shutil; however, I don't how to specify the path of the folder in the destination computer.

Below is the code I tried, but it gives me an error stating "Invalid Argument".  I think the path of the destination is incorrectly specified.

Can you please help?

```
import os
import shutil
import ntpath

ip_address="192.168.1.2"

source_file = "D:\\Test\\testfile.txt"

destination_file = ip_address + D:\\Test\\testfile.txt"

shutil.copyfile(source_file, destination_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're getting an `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument` is probably that the file in question is not shared anymore (or yet) with the recipient.

As of the Windows [*documentation*](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/file-sharing-over-a-network-in-windows-b58704b2-f53a-4b82-7bc1-80f9994725bf), you can give access to a specific file by doing this :

> 1. Right-click (or long-press) a file, and then select :
>    Show more options **>>** Give access to **>>** Specific people.
> 2. Select a user on the network to share the file with, or select Everyone to give all network users access to the file.

Only then, you can use [`shutil.copyfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile) and re-run your script :

```
import os
import shutil
import ntpath

ip_address ="192.168.1.2"

source_file = r"D:\Test\testfile.txt"
destination_file = ip_address + r"\Test\testfile.txt"

shutil.copyfile(source_file, destination_file)
```

*NB : You have to make sure that the folder `Test` exists in the recipient's computer and is writable.*

Comment: I followed your instructions and gave network access to the source file as well as ensured that destination folder is writable.

Unfortunately, I get the error:  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:  192.168.1.2\\Test\testfile.txt.

This error pertains to the destination.  I think the path of the destination is incorrect.  Does it need to be tweaked in any way?

Comment: Can you copy the path of the destination folder from the Windows explorer and paste it here ? If you are on Windows 11, you can right click on the folder and choose _Copy as path_.